# how to traverse between 2 cards on different screens in java swing app

Tags: java

> > I am creating an app in Java swing.
> > It has Screen_1 Screen_2 and Screen_3.
> > Now I want to go back from Screen_2 to a specific card in Screen_1
> > How to do that??

Comment: Use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: thats what i am doing

Comment: Screen1 has 3 cards

Comment: how to go to card number 2 in Screen_1 from Screen_2

Comment: I have no idea.  Edit your question and post a [mre] that I can copy into my IDE, test, and modify.

Comment: Does your _Swing_ application contain more than one [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)? And does each `JFrame` contain a `JPanel` whose layout manager is `CardLayout`? And do you want to switch between the different `JFrame`s? What action does the user perform in order to switch to a different `JFrame`? Does he click a `JButton`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe - card layouts can help you out - [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Code would be something like this:

```
JPanel parentPanel = (JPanel)getParent();
CardLayout layout = parentPanel.getLayout();
layout.show(panel, "...");
```